# Как объединить ячейки в новом xlsx файле подобно тому, как это есть в исходном xlsx файле?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Друзья, используя библиотеку ***openpyxl***, хочу скопировать определенные ячейки из одного xlsx файла в другой (новый). Скопировать ячейки получилось, как и скопировать их стили, но проблема возникла в другом: некоторые ячейки могут быть объединены (MergedCell) и при их вставке в новый xlsx файл они, конечно, не объединяются. Можете подсказать, в каком направлении думать и как эти ячейки объединить в новом файле подобно тому, как это есть в исходном xlsx файле?

Если нужно, то вот пример части кода:

```
import openpyxl
from copy import copy

path = r"C:\Users\somepath\example.xlsx"
head = "A1:J2" #Заголовок таблицы, в котором есть объединенные ячейки

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active

for row_number, row in enumerate(ws[head]):
    for col_number, cell in enumerate(row):
        ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1, cell.value)
        if cell.has_style:
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).font = copy(cell.font)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).fill = copy(cell.fill)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).border = copy(cell.border)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).protection = copy(cell.protection)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).quotePrefix = copy(cell. quotePrefix)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).pivotButton = copy(cell.pivotButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение следующее: перед началом копирования ячеек в новый xlsx файл сначала необходимо объединить ячейки в новом xlsx файле, воспользовавшись методом ws.merge_cells(), который принимает параметры - start_row, start_column, end_row и end_column.

Чтобы получить координаты объединенных ячеек из исходного xlsx файла, я воспользовался ws.merged_cells.ranges, который возвращает список координатов объединенных ячеек на листе, например, A1:A2 или С1:F1 и т.д. (class 'openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange').

Далее я воспользовался функцией openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(), которая в качестве параметра принимает строку-координату объединенной ячейки, например, "A1:A2" и возвращает tuple, где (min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row).

И эти координаты применил в качестве параметров ws.merge_cells() в новом xlsx файле.

Получившийся код, который работает:

```
import openpyxl
from copy import copy
from openpyxl.utils.cell import range_boundaries

path = r"C:\Users\somepath\example.xlsx"
head = "A1:J2" #Заголовок таблицы, в котором есть объединенные ячейки

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active

for _range in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
    boundaries = range_boundaries(str(_range))
    ws2.merge_cells(start_column=boundaries[0], start_row=boundaries[1],
                    end_column=boundaries[2], end_row=boundaries[3])

for row_number, row in enumerate(ws[head]):
    for col_number, cell in enumerate(row):
        ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1, cell.value)
        if cell.has_style:
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).font = copy(cell.font)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).fill = copy(cell.fill)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).border = copy(cell.border)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).protection = copy(cell.protection)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).quotePrefix = copy(cell.quotePrefix)
            ws2.cell(row_number+1, col_number+1).pivotButton = copy(cell.pivotButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не работает? Из документации `openpyxl.worksheet.merge.MergeCells(count=None, mergeCell=())`

```
for x in range(10):
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=x, start_column=1, end_row=x, end_column=4)
```

Comment: Да, это можно использовать, но для этого я должен получить координаты объединенных ячеек, но у меня их нет, потому что когда я обращаюсь к ячейке в исходном файле, то возвращается "class 'openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell" вида "<MergedCell 'Лист1'.A2>". Я нашел решение своего вопроса, в т.ч. с использованием метода "ws.merge_cells()". Сейчас напишу ответ. Спасибо!